# How can I add a Keyboard Toolbar to only specific TextFields in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm making a recipe app in SwiftUI and I'm trying to add a keyboard toolbar to only specific TextFields, but it applies to every TextField even though I added the toolbar to a specific TextField.

Here is my code for the toolbar.

```
ForEach(ingredients.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    TextField("Add Ingredient", text: $ingredients[index].ingredient)
         .toolbar {
              ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                  KeyboardToolbarView(text:$ingredients[index].ingredient)
              }
          }
}
```

This works but it's applied to every time whenever I am typing in a TextField. I only want it to be applied to specific TextFields throughout the whole app. Here is a screenshot of the toolbar.[Image of working toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNc5Y.png)

I only want the toolbar to show when the user is typing in one of the ingredient TextFields not any of the other ones, but if I go to type in any of the others the toolbar is present. Is there anyway to only show it for specific TextFields or hide it on the others?

Comment: I'd try adding a `@FocusState` to each `TextField` and then use a simple conditional to check if you should show the `ToolbarItem` or not.

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't work as expected. Sometimes the toolbar doesn't even show up when it should or the toolbar just shows up for every TextField.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `selection` variable that gets set when your `TextField` is selected.

Then, in your `.toolbar`, you can check for what `TextField` is being edited and then display your appropriate `Button` or `View` per row/individual field.

```
@State private var selection: Int?

ForEach(ingredients.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    TextField("Add Ingredient", text: $ingredients[index].ingredient, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
        self.selection = isEditing ? index : nil
    })
    .tag(index)
    .toolbar {
        if selection == index {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                KeyboardToolbarView(text:$ingredients[index].ingredient)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would propose edit to GRIV's answer:

        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
           if selection == index {
                KeyboardToolbarView(text:$ingredients[index].ingredient)
            }
            else { EmptyView() }
        }

This way it will be available for iOS before 16.

Answer (score 1):

Proposed backwards compatibility for [GRIV's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3092847/griv) answer:

```
@State private var selection: Int?

ForEach(ingredients.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    TextField("Add Ingredient", text: $ingredients[index].ingredient, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
        self.selection = isEditing ? index : nil
    })
    .tag(index)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            if selection == index {
                KeyboardToolbarView(text:$ingredients[index].ingredient)
            }
            else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```